# How to i SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView in my project

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey guys i want to SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView  in my project. What is the proper way to do it? Im trying to import it but failed. Sorry newbie here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jitpack.io and obtained the latest version. Try this out, it should work.

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.dinuscxj:LoadingDrawable:1d8bc27'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's already possible to add a library project via the IDE (-> without any problems). I do this by configuring the gradle files of my project like this:

create a folder in your root project directory named `libs`
copy the folder `datetimepicker-library` to libs
add this library in your settings.gradle with the following command:

```
include ':libs:datetimepicker-library'
```

go to your `build.gradle` file of your `AppProject` and add the following line to your `dependencies:`

```
compile project(':libs:datetimepicker-library')
```

at least you have to sync your gradle files: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
Please try this. If you get errors please post the log file.